# Why this program crashing?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2008, dll, firewall

I am writing a network program. it opens up a port in windows firewall and its port number too. I hv created a dll file which contains all codes to modify firewall. In this program I am using that dll. When I execute this for the first time, the program crashes before unloading the library. It doesnt show "Unloading Firewall DLL" ... But if I try again then it works fine (the program is allowed and port is opened in the firewall in the first try.)

Here is the code and the outputs:

```
    int Load_DLL(void)
{
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetModuleFileName(NULL,szPath,MAX_PATH);

    HINSTANCE Lib;
    WIN_FIREWALL addr;
    Log("Loading Firewall DLL ...");
    Lib = LoadLibrary(FIREWALL_DLL);
    if(Lib != NULL)
    {
        addr = (WIN_FIREWALL)GetProcAddress(Lib,"Win_Firewall");
        if(NULL != addr)
        {
            struct ManipFW mf = {};
            mf.OPCODE = ADDPORT;
            lstrcpy(mf.PortName,L"MSNet_Spool");
            mf.Port = PORT_I;
            (*addr)(mf,Log);
            memset(&mf,0,sizeof(mf));
            mf.OPCODE = ADDAPP;
            lstrcpy(mf.AppPath,szPath);
            lstrcpy(mf.AppName,L"MS_NET");
            (*addr)(mf,Log);
        }
        else 
            Log("Firewall GetProcAddress Failed \n");
        Log("Unloading Firewall DLL ...");
        FreeLibrary(Lib);

    }
    else
    {
        Log("Firewall DLL Load failed");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output for first try:

```
Loading Firewall DLL ...§4Port is not open in the firewall.

Port is now open in the firewall.

Authorized application  is disabled in the firewall.

Authorized application  is now enabled in the firewall.


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Output for the subsequent try:

```
Loading Firewall DLL ...í       Port is open in the firewall.

Authorized application is enabled in the firewall.

Unloading Firewall DLL ...
```

**This is the case if I execute the program using command promt in admin mode. But if I use the debugger in VS2008(running with admin rights), everything works fine from the first try.**

Comment: Have you got the calling convention correct in your WIN_FIREWALL typedef?

Comment: Also are your string buffers in `struct ManipFW` large enough for the strings you're writing into it?

Comment: Yes ofcourse, if string buffer wasnt enough then it couldnot have successfully added the it to firewall. but its doing that properly. and for the test case my buffer size if 260 bytes and my string ssize of way too less. and about the convention, yes it correct. coz it works from the second time .... I think there is some problem with the firewall dll which after modifying firewall doesnot do something that shld be done ... let me check again

Comment: Been a while since I programmed for Windows but I recall having problems with DLLs and EXEs sharing memory - allocate in the EXE and free in the DLL.  I'm wondering if Log is doing something that causes memory issues.

Comment: Your comment regarding command line vs debugger to me means you are corrupting memory somewhere.  Possibly in another thread.  Like @Rup says above, check string lengths.

Comment: What makes me uneasy is the garbage printed just after `Loading Firewall DLL ...`. That makes me think that your problem is just a symptom of a bigger problem.